# How can I prevent anyone from holding a reference to an object in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class like this

```
internal class  Report
{
    public Company TargetCompany { get; private set; }

    .... // other stuff
}
```

I do not want any one to be able to do this

```
Report r = GetReport();

Company c = r.TargetCompany;
```

but instead always use

```
r.TargetCompany
```

when they want access to the Company variable.

Is that possible? Does that even make sense?

Comment: What does GetReport method do?

Comment: @Yogendra, I just put in the GetReport function there as a place holder for stuff you would need to get a Report object. It's not really relevant.

@Alexdej, The reason I would like to do this is because I always want users of the Company obj to deal with the latest version of the Company obj stored inside the Report obj. It might not be apparent from the example I used above but imagine some unrelated event causes a new Company obj to be created in the Report obj. Now if someone is still holding on to a ref to the old Company obj, they are dealing with stale data. I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose a proxy interface in Report, which calls the equivalent interface in Company, and make Company private, so that you completely control (encapsulate even) access to the Company object.

Comment: you're not answering the question (as note under your comment else where)

Comment: @Rune. I think I'm answering the question "is that possible?". It's not a directly supported language feature, but it is possible to achieve the stated goal. As others have flatly stated "no", I thought I would add that actually, yes it is *possible*.

Comment: The flatly stated "no" is the correct version. It's not possible to stop some one from storing a reference to an exposed object. It's possible not to expose a referance to the object at all true but that is not the question. The example given is exposing the referance and asking if it's some how possible to make sure no one stores that referance

Comment: Indeed. As that had already been answered, I was merely expanding by offering a working solution to show how you *might* achieve the desired effect if you felt it was useful to do so. I'm not sure why trying to help in this way is controversial.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible.

And no, it really doesn't make sense either. Maybe if you explain your reasoning we'll understand a little better.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense sometimes - it's really just higher-level encapsulation. Imagine you have a logging Stream and a Reporter class. Rather than giving clients access to the Stream directly, you replicate the useful parts (a limited subset) of the Stream's interface in the Reporter, and force clients to ask the Reporter to act as a proxy for the Stream. This encapsulates the Stream so that you can change it (e.g. to send the log messages as UDP datagrams rather than writing them to a stream). Or you might only expose the write API so that clients can't Close() the stream.

Comment: But if that's the case, then you're not truly doing what the OP is asking for here. You're mearly implenting the Facade pattern...which is not what is being asked for here.

Comment: @Jason: Sure, but that's not what's being asked for. What's being asked for is the ability to return a reference to a caller, but only for the purpose of calling something else, not for storing in a local variable. *That* doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: I was simply trying to suggest an approach that achieves the stated goal. If you expose all methods of the encapsulated object, you are achieving the aim of not being able to touch it, and forcing clients to call its methods via the proxy. It allows the proxy to encapsulate and control the life-cycle of the child object. I agree with you - I don't understand the specific case illustrated in the question - but essentially it's just a facade/proxy that is being requested, if a rather unconventional usage.

Comment: @JasonW @JustinN @JonS Thx for the discussion. As @JasonW said, the result I am trying to get can be achieved by using a proxy (or facade). I was however looking to see if the language natively supported what I wanted. Why I think it makes sense is that the Report obj could change that Company obj and while that change would be reflected for any externally held reference, there could be cases where the Company object needs to be replaced (as opposed to be updated). In that case, yea, a proxy would work, but it would be nice to be able to say for this property, prevent any external references.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not possible.  The closest thing you can do is to provide wrappers to only allow access to the members within TargetCompany (not the company reference itself), or to return a copy of your internal TargetCompany member, preventing the internal one from being referenced (which has no real value).